# No me aparecen graficas de apache echarts en mi aplicacion con django

Tags: javascript, python, django, echarts

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion con el framework django, en uno de mis archivos html quiero mostrar una grafica con apache echarts, revise el codigo pero no encuentro porque la me aparece la grafica.

```html
const getOptionsChart=()=>{
    return {
        xAxis: {
          type: 'category',
          data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
        },
        yAxis: {
          type: 'value'
        },
        series: [
          {
            data: [
              120,
              {
                value: 200,
                itemStyle: {
                  color: '#a90000'
                }
              },
              150,
              80,
              70,
              110,
              130
            ],
            type: 'bar'
          }
        ]
      };
}


const initChart=()=>{
    var chartDOM = document.getElementById('chart')
    var mychart = echarts.init(chartDOM);
    var option = getOptionsChart();
    option && mychart.setOption(option);
   
};

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    initChart();
});
```

a que se puede deber este comportamiento si en mi html tengo la linea:

Comment: Hola Erick.py, bienvenido, parece que el comentario final salio cortado, faltaría tu "html", aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.